# Heat pump blower motor cycles on/off after running 140 seconds

Tags: heat-pump

Standard Trane split heat pump, condenser outside blower inside.
Usually the system will run normally but after 2 min 20 seconds the blower motor will cycle on and off randomly for 20 seconds. Then run perfectly for the rest of the heating cycle.
One time the problem occurred at 3 min 20 seconds.
Expert checked system and said needed new motor.
Now has new motor but still same problem.
Anybody have any ideas.

Comment: What is the ambient temperature? And is this the indoor blower or the outdoor condenser fan that's cycling?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you mean by "cycle on and off randomly"?

Comment: Can you see the error LED's on the inside unit? There can be approx 75 different codes on some of the units and the error codes are the only way to figure out what is really happening. Cover switch not made, dirty air filter, high condensate all can cause strange problems.

Answer (score -1):

Your system is trying to pull air it cannot supply. You have a dirty air filter; clean or replace it.